# Unable to call Django function for inserting data in postgres db

Tags: html, django, postgresql, django-models

I am running the below code however when i submit create.html template it goes directly to home.html without inserting any record in postgres db. I believe, the function "create" is not called at all. Kindly assist

I tried directing the function

*** views.py ***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Product

def home(request):
   return render(request, 'products/home.html')


@login_required
def create(request):
   if request.method =='POST':
        product = Product()
        product.title = request.POST['title']
        product.save()
        return redirect('home')
   else:
       return render(request, 'products/create.html')
```

*** urls.py ***

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('create',views.create,name='create'),]
```

*** models.py ***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

*** apps.py ***

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
   name = 'products'
```

*** Main url.py ***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from products import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),]
```

*** urls.py ***

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('create',views.create,name='create'),]
```

*** create.html ***

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block content%}

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'create' %}" enctype =       "multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}

Title:
<br/>
<input type="text"  name = "title"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Add      Product"/>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

I was expecting the record to be inserted in database (postgres) and I should be able to validate it using "django administration" page. 
I am able to add the record manually via "django administration" page but not via above html form

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you aren't validating the data at all.  You need to get the data from `cleaned_data`, which is only available after validating. Try referring to this, as you have a very simple example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Hi - To simplify the process, I just displayed minimal code. Original code has  validation checks. My issue is that "create" function is not called at all.

Comment: Is that your main urls.py? Or is it being included in another one? Show both complete URL files if possible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Please see the main url.py file above for your reference. thanks

Comment: Hmm can't see anything obvious wrong here. Do you have any JavaScript on that page?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Not here but i do have Javascript in login/signup section of home page. However I am able to successfully login and sign up with all requisite checks too. In the above create.html page i do not have any Javascript.